# How to print or echo a random php string on page load or refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using WordPress' Revolution Slider (aka Slider Revolution) in which I have create 3 different sliders.  Each slider only contains 1 video each which I am using as a full width background on the home page kind of like the Aribnb website.

I want the sliders to load in random order so that each time a user visits the home page they get a random new video/slider. My markup for the sliders  receptively for each is as follows...

```
<?php putRevSlider("slider1") ?>
<?php putRevSlider("slider2") ?>
<?php putRevSlider("slider3") ?>
```

How can I make just one of these print or echo at random on my home page each time the page is refreshed?

RELEVANT INFO: The reason I made 3 sliders instead of adding all 3 videos in 1 single slider and setting them in random order as RevSlider already supports is because I don't want the videos to play one after the other which is why I have set each one of them to loop on their own individual slider.

Comment: I would recommend Kenny's answer, Don't use JS for something your php can do before it hits the front end

Comment: Thanks, Kenny's answer did it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php
$SliderNumber = rand(1,3);              //random number between 1 and 3
$SliderName = "slider" . $SliderNumber; //will either be "slider1", "slider2", or "slider3"
putRevSlider($SliderName);
?>
```

Comment: As mentioned in the following answer, using `mt_rand` is better performance

Comment: @SethMcClaine I have read the documentation before that mt_rand claims to be four times faster. Every speed test that I have seen doesn't not substantiate this. Further, even if this were true, which it isn't, a random number between 1 and 3 you will notice no time difference, even if it were 10 or 20 times faster. But it isn't faster.

Answer (score 6):

```
  <?php
        $random = mt_rand(1,3); //Get a random number from 1-3
        putRevSlider("slider".$random); 
  ?>
```

Comment: 4x faster than `rand()`. Code has greater level of consolidation.

Comment: Thank you for noticing the little things Marcus :D

Comment: You could also decrease code count with <?php putRevSlider("slider".mt_rand(1,3)); ?>

Comment: @NeilMasters you mean `<?php putRevSlider("slider".mt_rand(1,3)); ?>` ? ;)

Comment: This is a great post and comments, however, I have wrestled with this consolidation issue before and I have come to the conclusion that I think it is better to not consolidate in cases like this where it doesn't add that much to computing. The readability gained, especially for someone newer, is not worth the extra time spent 6 months down the line when you are debugging. IMO